# Newbie Question - Breaking a Function into two

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am new to python and I have a function that I need to break into two parts. Previously it was one function but after some advice from someone that knows way more than me, I was given the tip that my function did too much, and I need to break it down to two separate things; so here I am.

Below is the code broken into two parts.

I am wondering do I have to mention the `pathlist` in both functions?

What this is supposed to do is check if the files exist and then if they do then run the second function to remove the actual directories.

```
def check_directory(pathslist):
    for path in pathslist:
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
            remove_directory(pathslist)

dirs_to_delete = [
    'C:\MyDirectoryPath1',
    'C:\MyDirectoryPath2',
    'C:\MyDirectoryPath3'

 ]

def remove_directory(pathslist):
    for path in pathslist:
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)
            print(colored('Found ' + path + ' removing', 'green'))
```

Comment: "*Do I have to mention the pathlist in both functions?"* If you want to perform operations on an input, you sure do.

Comment: I guess I was second guessing it was able to pull and use the pathlist from the other function or do the directories need to be listed in both spots?

Comment: The advice to break this up is vaguely bogus. You should _certainly_ not have identical code in many places.

Comment: While `\M` is harmless, you should generally use double backslashes, forward slashes, or raw strings when passing around Windows file names.

Comment: @tripleee The advice to break up the code is good; I just don't think OP did it in the best way.

Comment: If you liked an answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Not exactly.  If you are passing in the entire pathslist to `remove_directory`, you're going to try to remove each one whether or not it exists, making your check_directory function unnecessary.  I think what you mean is in your check_directory function to only pass the path that exists in to remove_directory:

```
def check_directory(pathslist):
    for path in pathslist:
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
            remove_directory(path)

dirs_to_delete = [
    'C:\MyDirectoryPath1',
    'C:\MyDirectoryPath2',
    'C:\MyDirectoryPath3'

 ]


def remove_directory(path):
     shutil.rmtree(path)
     print(colored('Found ' + path + ' removing', 'green'))
```

You may want to try writing a comment for every function you write describing what it does.  The second you use the word "and" or an additional verb, that's a hint that you may be better off splitting the function into multiple parts (that's just a rule of thumb, not an absolute).  In addition, you want to avoid repeating code--if you have the same lines of code in two separate functions, that's another hint that you need to rethink your design.

Edit:  As pointed out in the comments, the way you've written it means that calling `check_directory` will remove the directory if it exists.  It seems reasonable to expect that someone would call `check_directory` for reasons other than wanting to remove it, and you'd be better off having `remove_directory` call `check_directory` rather than the other way around:

```
    def check_directory(path):
         # returns true if path is an existing directory
         return os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path)

    def remove_directory(pathlist):
        for path in pathlist:
            if check_directory(path):
                shutil.rmtree(path)
                print(colored('Found ' + path + ' removing', 'green'))
```

Comment: I've upvoted because you're answering the direct question. A bit out of scope of the topic at hand, but the method name `check_directory` becomes a bit mis-leading if this were to become part of a bigger project. Someone using `check_directory` might be curious to know why it's also deleting the directory they pass in. A better paradigm would be to call `check_directory()` in `remove_directory()`

Comment: @thumbtackthief - I edited my code but when calling the function i am getting a error - TypeError: check_directory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'

Comment: @JasonLucas That means somewhere you're calling `check_directory` without passing in an argument.

Comment: to call the function "check_directory" to start checking for folders do i need to do anything other then check_directory()

Comment: Are you using the top version of the code in the answer or the bottom?

Comment: I am using the bottom

Comment: @JasonLucas `check_directory()` takes the parameter of the path you want to check.  I didn't test my code above but it should be correct.